# Executing TestNG xml from Kotlin Jar

Tags: kotlin, testng, classpath, filepath, executable-jar

Noob here,

I have a Kotlin/Appium/TestNG project that I am trying to package as an executable jar to use as part of my jenkins job.

Below is my main method, I am trying to figure out how to add XML files to my suites array using the xml file jar path.

It works if I give it an absolute path to "AppiumRegression.xml", but will fail to find the xml once I attempt to run the jar on another machine since the xml file doesn't exist

I've checked the jar contents and verified the xml exists within the package(TestNG xml files are in resources directory) but for the life of me have not been able to figure out a way to use jar file path to add suites.

```
class Main {
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val testng = TestNG()
        val suites = Lists.newArrayList<String>()
        suites.add("PATH TO XML FILE/AppiumRegression.xml") // <--- need jar filepath
        testng.setTestSuites(suites)
        testng.run()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have worked around the issue by extracting the directory that contains the xml files from the jar before executing for now. Please let me know if anyone comes across a better solution